# Slow .findByIdAndUpdate().lean() with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, mongoose

I'm needing to update/save documents with sizes between 100KB - 800KB. Update operations like so, `console.time('save'); await doc.findByIdAndUpdate(...).lean(); console.timeEnd('save');`, are taking over 5s - 10s to finish. The updates contain ~50KB at most.

The large document property which is being updated has a structure like so:

```
{ 
    largeProp: [{
        key1: { key1A:val, key1B:val, ... 10 more ... },
        key2: { key1A:val, key1B:val, ... 10 more ... },
        key3: { key1A:val, key1B:val, ... 10 more ... },
        ...300 more...
    }, ...100 more... ]
}
```

I'm using a Node.js server on Ubuntu VM with mongoose.js with MongoDB hosted on a separate server. The MongoDB server is does not show any unusual load, it usually stays under 7% CPU, however my Node.js server will hit 100% CPU usage with **just this** update operation (after a `.findById()` and some quick logic, 8ms-52ms). The `.findById()` takes about 500ms - 1s for this same object.

I need these saves to be much faster, and I don't understand why this is so slow.

Comment: Profile your application and identify where the time is being spent.

Comment: This is what i've done. As mentioned, other operations inside this route take between 8ms and 52ms. Specifically, the `collection.findByIdAndUpdate().lean()` takes 5s to 10s. This is a mongoose (an ODM abstraction layer) method. So, i'm hoping there is greater knowledge out there about the speed of this particular method.

Comment: Keep profiling into that method.

Comment: If you suspect the issue is not in your application, write a script that performs the operation that takes 5-10 seconds after inserting the required data, add the script to the question.

Comment: Alright. I will do that tomorrow when I can think about this more clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not do much more profiling on the Mongoose query. Instead I tested out a native MongoDB query and it significantly improved the speed, so I will be using native MongoDB going forward.

```
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Types;
let result = await mongoose.connection.collection('collection1')
            .aggregate([
                { $match: { _id: ObjectId(gameId) } },
                { $lookup: {
                        localField:'field1',
                        from:'collection2',
                        foreignField:'_id',
                        as:'field1'
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: '$field1' },
                { $project: {
                        _id: 1,
                        status: 1,
                        createdAt: 1,
                        slowArrProperty: { $slice: ["$positions", -1] } },
                        updatedAt: 1
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$slowArrProperty" }
            ]).toArray();

 if (result.length < 1) return {};
 return result[0];
```

This query, as well as doing some restructuring of my data model solved my issue. Specifically, the document property that was very large and causing issues, I used the above `{ $slice: ["$positions", -1] } }` to only return one of the objects in the array at a time.

Just from switching to native MongoDB queries (within the mongoose wrapper), I saw between 60x and 3000x improvements on query speeds.